# How to move subfolders from folders with different name to parent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files-folders, pop-os

I'm using Pop OS and want to move all files in each one of these folders to the parent. How do I do it quickly?

[image: image of the folders]

Comment: Welcome to the community. I edited your question for clarity and added the image - if I misunderstood your meaning please correct my edit. I'd suggest checking out https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask (and links therein) for advice on writing good quality questions. In general going through the Help section of each SE community you join is a good idea. These aren't discussion forums, so the rules are a bit different.

Comment: Can you use the terminal window? If so, use the `cd` command to navigate to the parent and there `mv -i */* .` meaning move all files (assuming none are hidden) from subdirectories to the current (which is the parent). I add the option `-i` to warn about overwriting in case of name clashes.

Comment: Thx so so so so much for both of Peregrino69 and Bernhard Bodenstorfer thx so much for real this helped me so much

Comment: Before moving anything, make sure the directories only contain files. If there are subdirectories, those with their content will also be moved to current dir. If you then delete all directories in current dir, you will lose the content still in the subdirectories.